# How can I add object to array by certain condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, key

I try like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clubs = [ 
        {id: 1, name : 'chelsea'},
        {id: 2, name : 'city'},
        {id: 3, name : 'liverpool'}
    ];
    var newClub = {id: 4, name: 'manchester united'}
    for(var i=0; i<clubs.length; i++) {
        if(clubs[i].id!=newClub.id) {
            clubs.push(newClub);
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(clubs);
</script>
```

I want to add condition. If id of newClub object is not exist in the clubs array, then I want to add the object to the array

It works

But I ask. Is that the best way? Or is there another better way?

Comment: *"It works'* No, it doesn't.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I check in the console, it works

Comment: Run it a second time, and you'll find you push the same club in again. You're pushing any time the **first** club in the array isn't a match for the new club.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It works

No, it doesn't. :-) You're pushing the new club if the **first** entry isn't a match:

```js
var clubs = [ 
    {id: 1, name : 'chelsea'},
    {id: 2, name : 'city'},
    {id: 3, name : 'liverpool'}
];
function pushClub(newClub) {
  for(var i=0; i<clubs.length; i++) {
      if(clubs[i].id!=newClub.id) {
          clubs.push(newClub);
          break;
      }
  }
}
var newClub = {id: 4, name: 'manchester united'}
pushClub(newClub);
pushClub(newClub);
console.log(JSON.stringify(clubs));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
Note that there are two id = 4 clubs.
```

You need to loop through the *whole* array before you know whether you should add the new item.

I'd probably use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see whether the item was present:

```
if (!clubs.some(c => c.id == newClub.id)) {
    clubs.push(newClub);
}
```

```js
var clubs = [ 
    {id: 1, name : 'chelsea'},
    {id: 2, name : 'city'},
    {id: 3, name : 'liverpool'}
];
function pushClub(newClub) {
  if (!clubs.some(c => c.id == newClub.id)) {
    clubs.push(newClub);
  }
}
var newClub = {id: 4, name: 'manchester united'}
pushClub(newClub);
pushClub(newClub);
console.log(JSON.stringify(clubs));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
Note that there is only one id = 4 club.
```

I'm using an ES2015+ arrow function there, but you could use an ES5 traditional function:

```
if (!clubs.some(function(c) { return c.id == newClub.id; })) {
    clubs.push(newClub);
}
```

The loop is in `some`, which returns `true` if the callback ever returns a truthy value, or `false` if it never does. (It also stops early when the callback returns a truthy value.)

---

**If** you wanted to *update* the existing club if present, I'd use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead:

```
var existingClub = clubs.find(c => c.id == newClub.id);
if (existingClub) {
    existingClub.name = newClub.name;
} else {
    clubs.push(newClub);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because you insert in the first loop the object. You need to check all elements and if all element does not contain the wanted id, you could add the object top the array.

**Not working code**, spot the index.

```js
var clubs = [{ id: 1, name: 'chelsea' }, { id: 2, name: 'city' }, { id: 3, name: 'liverpool' }],
    newClub = { id: 4, name: 'manchester united' },
    i;
    
for (i = 0; i < clubs.length; i++) {
  if (clubs[i].id != newClub.id) {
    clubs.push(newClub);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(i, clubs);
```

**Working code** with a check if all clubs do not contain the new `id`.

```js
var clubs = [{ id: 1, name: 'chelsea' }, { id: 2, name: 'city' }, { id: 3, name: 'liverpool' }],
    newClub = { id: 4, name: 'manchester united' };
    
if (!clubs.some(({ id }) => id === newClub.id)) {
    clubs.push(newClub);
}

console.log(clubs);
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this

`arr1.some` function

```js
var clubs = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'chelsea'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'city'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'liverpool'
  }
];
var newClub = {
  id: 4,
  name: 'manchester united'
}
let found = clubs.some(r => r.id == newClub.id)
for (var i = 0; i < clubs.length; i++) {
  if (!clubs.some(r => r.id == newClub.id)) {
    clubs.push(newClub);
  }
}
console.log(clubs);
```